# start Rserve from Rprofile.site

Tags: r, linux, rserve

I want to start Rserve using Rprofile.site which look like this

```
 .First <- function(){
    library(Rserve)
    Rserve(args="--RS-conf /usr/lib64/R/etc/Rserv.conf")
    source("/usr/lib64/R/etc/InvestorToolBox.R")
    }
```

But for some raison when i run R it enter a loop where it keep running instance of Rserve as shown In the screen shot

> Starting Rserve: /usr/lib64/R/bin/R CMD
>   /usr/lib64/R/library/Rserve/libs//Rserve --RS->conf /usr/lib64/R/etc/
>   Rserv.conf
>
> R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree" Copyright (C)
>   2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
>   x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are
>   welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()'
>   or 'licence()' for distribution details.
>
> Natural language support but running in an English locale
>
> R is a collaborative project with many contributors. Type
>   'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite
>   R or R packages in publications.
>
> Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
>   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help. Type 'q()' to
>   quit R.
>
> Starting Rserve: /usr/lib64/R/bin/R CMD
>   /usr/lib64/R/library/Rserve/libs//Rserve --RS->conf /usr/lib64/R/etc/
>   Rserv.conf
>
> R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree" Copyright (C)
>   2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
>   x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are
>   welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()'
>   or 'licence()' for distribution details.
>
> Natural language support but running in an English locale
>
> R is a collaborative project with many contributors. Type
>   'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite
>   R or R packages in publications.
>
> Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
>   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help. Type 'q()' to
>   quit R.
>
> Starting Rserve: /usr/lib64/R/bin/R CMD
>   /usr/lib64/R/library/Rserve/libs//Rserve --RS-
>
> conf /usr/lib64/R/etc/ Rserv.conf

Can you tell me why or what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Basic user misunderstanding of how things work

Answer (score 6):

*Edit:* tl;dr is you are doing it wrong. By being in `~/.Rprofile` to launch you get an R process which reads `~/.Rprofile` and launches ... and you get yourself recursion.  The simple fix is to use `Rserve` the way it is meant to be used.

One tends to start Rserve outside of R:

```
edd@max:~$ R CMD Rserve 

R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Rserv started in daemon mode.
edd@max:~$ pstree -p | grep Rserve
           |-Rserve(24569)
edd@max:~$
```

There are options for RServe to use its specific config files to set particular startup parameters, authentication choices etc pp

Comment: i am sorry if i didn't understand you , i am running Rserve with with specific config file as `Rserve(args="--RS-conf /usr/lib64/R/etc/Rserv.conf")`  but it run serveral times,,, i tried to run it as `R CMD Rserve(args="--RS-conf /usr/lib64/R/etc/Rserv.conf")` but it doesn't work

Comment: your answer has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Nope -- rather you do not seem to grapsp that launching Rserve starts an R process which reads `.Rprofile` so that you obviously start a recursion.

Comment: ok now that was helpful , can you please tell me how to run Rserve outside of R with specific config file.?

Comment: Have you found the [Rserve documentation](https://rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html)?